# Visual Studio's "go to definition" goes to a wrong function/line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So this happened after my project got to around 6-7k lines of codes, and for some reason go to definition goes to a wrong line for some of the functions. This only happens for old functions inside of a specific .c file.

So when I use an old function inside of that .c file and try to use F12, it goes to a wrong line/function, almost feels like its going to its old line number.

I'm using visual studio 2019, how can i fix this?

Comment: this still occurs in Visual Studio 2022 17.3.0 we should file a bug. the need to frequently manually delete a hidden folder to resolve this is a shame given the maturity of the product.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface It seems to me that it only happens when the project gets really big, never happens on small projects. Is it the same for you?

Comment: no I have just a couple of files, no more than roughly 61000 lines of code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Deleting the .vs folder will fix this issue but it will delete some settings.

Recreating the database fixed the issue for me: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Recreate Database == True. Then restart Visual Studios.

[image]

Comment: Which settings will deleting the .vs causes to get deleted? Aren't the project settings stored in .vcxproj* files?

Comment: According to [link](https://ourtechroom.com/tech/vs-folder-in-visual-studio-can-delete-it/), "you may lose user state related to solutions such as build configurations, local debug settings, open tabs, Project Configuration such as Profile type, Launch type, and so on". Other than that, I'm not really sure what else (if any) gets deleted, but I'd rather not take my chances.

Comment: Recreating the database works for me w/o deleting .vs directory.

Comment: Recreating database worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Solved. Should I leave "Recreating database"=true or revert back?

Comment: This should be a hotkey considering how often VS corrupts itself...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Close VS
- Delete the .vs folder
- Reopen VS

Works for me